# Несколько сообщений на одну команду

Tags: python, aiogram

Попробовал сделать вот так, не работает.

```
elif message.text == '▫️A':
    await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, open('videos/mid.mp4', 'rb'), open('videos/mid2.mp4', 'rb'))
```

Два `elif` на одно сообщение "A" тоже не помогло.

Comment: Что это за непонятный кусок кода? Что вы хотите от нас? Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Хочу, чтобы на одно сообщение "A" отправил два видео.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так а в чем проблема просто сделать два сенд_видео?

```
await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, open('videos/mid.mp4', 'rb')) 
await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, open('videos/mid2.mp4', 'rb'))
```

Comment: Уже догадался, спасибо xd

Comment: Ставьте галку тогда, слева от ответа